# How to concat special characters as sting to a text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, special-characters

How to concat character `\` as a string to a text in javascript?
I want to write this code line in javascript:

```
var x = "$$\" + $("#formul").val() + "$$";
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the backslash:

```
var x = "$$\\" + $("#formul").val() + "$$";
```

The problem you have currently is that the backslash is the escape character. It escapes the following `"` character so your string doesn't close.